# Using loops in Jasmine (with injected service)

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm using `jasmine 2.3.`
Following this: http://tosbourn.com/using-loops-in-jasmine/ I placed a FOR loop directly in the '`describe`' nested function

```
describe('service Profile', function() {
  var ProfileService;
  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app.services.profile');
    inject(function(_ProfileService_) {
      ProfileService = _ProfileService_;
    });
  });
  describe('method setProfile', function() {
    function setProfileTest(key) {
      it('should set the object profile', function() {
        expect(ProfileService.profile[key]).toBeUndefined();
      });
    }

    for (var key in ProfileService.profile) {
      if (ProfileService.profile.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        setProfileTest(key);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that outside the '`it`' function, `ProfileService` still `undefined`.

Comment: It means it is not injected.Check in karma screen and make sure corresponding file is included in karma.config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need `ProfileService` to be injected, the loop must run after the `beforeEach` block.

I can see two solutions. Either:

Use a hard-coded list of profiles and iterate through them. Eg- instead of

```
 for (var key in ProfileService.profile) {
```

do

```
for (var key in ['profile1', 'profile2'...) {
```

or load the profiles from an external file.

OR

Put the for loop inside of the `it` test:

```
it('should set the object profile', function() {
  for (var key in ProfileService.profile) {
    if (ProfileService.profile.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      expect(ProfileService.profile[key]).toBeUndefined();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The way I usually do it is with hard-coded values. That's a better test anyway.

Comment: Most likely that's better, but it depends on what you're testing here. The OP seems to be asking about testing the `ProfileService` but it might be that the loading of the profiles is outside the scope of this unit test. In this case it is perfectly fine IMO to use the `ProfileService` instance itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `describe` block creates the `it` blocks, then the `beforeEach` runs, then the it blocks, so, yes, `ProfileService` won't be defined when the describe block is setting up the `it` blocks if you define it in a `beforeEach`. However, `beforeEach` is not the only place you can use `inject`. What happens if you try something like:

```
describe('method setProfile',
    inject(
        function(ProfileService) {
             //your code here
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: I would be very surprised if this works. The reason is that in this situation, the injector has not been created yet.